# How to disable dijit ConfirmDialog button

Tags: javascript, dojo

How can i disable the Ok button on dijit/ConfirmDialog?

```
var lasloLoginFormDialog = new ConfirmDialog({
    title: "Login",
    closable: false,
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Jason96/mqyyp20u/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confirmDialog has an **okButton** attribute that represents the **OK** button.

You can set it to disabled.

```
lasloLoginFormDialog.show();
lasloLoginFormDialog.okButton.set('disabled',true); // add this line after show
```

Comment: Thanks. Gotta love the lackluster dojo docs, amirite? Gonna wire this up with the `onValidStateChange` event to monitor the contained form. I hope it works...